# git remove duplicate remote URLs

Tags: git

I was using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/8520798) to add multiple remote repository URLs. I by mistake added same remote url by using this command twice :

```
git remote set-url origin --push --add <a remote>
```

So now `git remote -v` shows this:

```
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (push) // remote-1
origin  https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (push) // duplicate reference to same remote-1
origin  https://bitbucket.com/<user>/<repo>.git (push) // remote-2
```

So now, whenever i push, git pushes 3 times, assuming there are 3 URLs.
How can i remove this duplicate URL, while keeping the original & the new remote reference.

Comment: Try out `git remote rm repourl` and then add the same remote back again.

Comment: @RohanAsokan doesnt work

Comment: `git remote set-url --push --delete origin <url>` should remove that push URL. Then you can just add it once again. Does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like

`git remote set-url --push --delete origin <url>` and then re-add the URL only once.

The git documentation on `set-url` states:

> set-url
> Changes URLs for the remote. Sets first URL for remote  that matches regex  (first URL if no  is given) to . If  doesn’t match any URL, an error occurs and nothing is changed.
>
> With --push, push URLs are manipulated instead of fetch URLs.
>
> With --add, instead of changing existing URLs, new URL is added.
>
> With --delete, instead of changing existing URLs, all URLs matching regex  are deleted for remote . Trying to delete all non-push URLs is an error.

So we can just combine the `--push` and `--delete` parameters to achieve what we want.